# Gmail : have all messages (read/unread) in one area?

Tags: gmail

Is there an option to not have Gmail separate read and unread emails? I just want to go to inbox and see all the mail. I can figure out for myself whether it's read or unread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, anytime you can change your Gmail inbox setting.

From the [Inbox styles and settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186534?hl=en):

> 1. Open [Gmail](https://www.gmail.com).
> 2. Click the *gear* in the top right.
> 3. Select **Settings**.
> 4. Select the **Inbox** tab.
> 5. In the “Inbox type” section, select an inbox style in the drop-down menu.
> 6. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page.